# Is there a way to do a join with cases

Tags: sql-server, function, sql-server-2000, table-functions

Is there a way to make a join with cases?

Something like

```
select * from abba 
   case when a=b then 
      join acdc on abba.id=acdc.id
   when b=c then 
      join bebop on abba.id=bebop.id 
   end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Best regards
Joe

Comment: Isn't this what the `on` part does? You can union the two other tables and join `on` your condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to LEFT JOIN both tables and select the *value* based on the CASE condition:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN a=b THEN acdc.myField ELSE bebop.myField END AS myField
  FROM abba 
       LEFT JOIN acdc ON abba.id=acdc.id 
       LEFT JOIN bebop ON abba.id=bebop.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If the query is non-dynamic then no since `case` statement only returns a literal value such as `string`, `int`, or other data-types.

But there is a work-around - **dynamic sql**. You treat the entire statement as a string. Then you can work your cases inside the string.

For example:

```
declare @query varchar(1000)
set @query = 'select * from abba '+
                case when @a=@b then 'join acdc on abba.id=acdc.id'
                     when @b=@c then 'join bebop on abba.id=bebop.id'
                end
exec(@query)
```

But ofcourse, your a=b & b=c must be some sql variable.